# How to force the reload of a page since ListView.builder doesn't update on list change?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried using different things and for now it works with Hive, but I wanted to load data from firebase(in case the user is logged in). I'm using the following code. I get no errors it's only that after I login using another page and I get back on homepage it doesn't show the data but it loads it since when I add another person it triggers a refresh and shows also the other data.

In the home page:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      data.load();
    });
```

then in the body I use the ListView.builder

```
: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.listobjects.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListData(
            name: data.listobjects[index].name,
                        surname: data.listobjects[index].surname,
        )
    }
)
```

In the data.dart:

```
Future<void> load() async {
    if (_myBox.get("box") != null) {
      listobjects = _myBox.get("box");
    }
    else if (_firebaseAuth.currentUser!=null) {
      final String currentUserId = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid;
      await _fireStore.collection('users').doc(currentUserId).collection('list').get().then(
        (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
          ListData newload = ListData(name: element['name'] ?? '', 
          surname: element['surname'] ??  '');
          listobjects.add(newload);
        })
      );
      update(); //Saves it locally
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you rebuild your widget? What does updateData do?

Comment: I don't know how to rebuild it, I searched and everything suggest setState that in my case fails, I tried using await to avoid issues when it loads the list from the server but nothing. updateData saves the data locally using hive.

Answer (score 0):

```
setState(() { updateData(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the issue is that I tried that and nothing changed. updateData() only saves the list locally using Hive.